# How to print data from node Api to Angular Table.? While printing data it's showing undefined element

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

I'm trying to print data in the angular table, the data is coming from a node in JSON format. But while printing t's showing undefined even in console data is showing.
I have attached the JSON response image as well.

I'm fetching data from MongoDB using and sending data to Angular using API.Data is coming but issue is that it's not printing in the table.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Date registered</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let x of data ">
                <td>{{x.serial}}</td>
                <td>2012/01/01</td>
                <td>Member</td>
                <td>
                  <span class="badge ba+dge-success">Active</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

JSON Repsone From API

```
{
code: 0,
message: "success",
data: {
labels: [
{
_id: "605b262c36c70c354015a945",
serial: "12345",
sourceApi: "ASDASD",
resultApi: "ASDASD",
labelApi: "ASDASD",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "605b26bd36c70c354015a946",
serial: "3333",
sourceApi: "sdfdg",
resultApi: "sdsf",
labelApi: "gggg",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "605b26ea2e5ea63080dd4796",
serial: "3333",
sourceApi: "sdfdg",
resultApi: "sdsf",[enter image description here][1]
labelApi: "gggg",
__v: 0
}
]
}
}
```

TS file code

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit{
  public data?:any;
  constructor(private api:ApiServiceService) { 

    this.api.getDataApi().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    })
   

  }

 

  dtOptions: any = {}; 
  ngOnInit(){
  this.dtOptions = {
    "paging"  : true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info"    : true
  };

  }
```

Comment: Try using `this.data = data[0]`. It would be a lot better if you could add image of your JSON response.

Comment: JSON Response is Added in the description sir

{
code: 0,
message: "success",
data: {
labels: [
{
_id: "605b262c36c70c354015a945",
serial: "12345",
sourceApi: "ASDASD",
resultApi: "ASDASD",
labelApi: "ASDASD",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "605b26bd36c70c354015a946",
serial: "3333",
sourceApi: "sdfdg",
resultApi: "sdsf",
labelApi: "gggg",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "605b26ea2e5ea63080dd4796",
serial: "3333",
sourceApi: "sdfdg",
resultApi: "sdsf",
labelApi: "gggg",
__v: 0
}
]
}
}

I wanted to get labels

Answer (score 0):

your JSON consists of some other data which are not needed to populate data.

In your JSON label is consists of an array of the object so we have to assign that to "data" variable

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit{
public data?:any;
constructor(private api:ApiServiceService) { 

this.api.getDataApi().subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data.data.labels;
})
```

}

Comment: when I add 2nd .data it says 'Property doesn't exist on type Object'

Comment: this.data = data.data['labels'];

Comment: core.js:6162 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let x of data ">
                <td>{{x?.serial}}</td>
                <td>2012/01/01</td>
                <td>Member</td>
                <td>
                  <span class="badge ba+dge-success">Active</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            
            </tbody>

Comment: data.data['labels'];

Comment: Do one thing log the data in the console and paste the response here. console.log("this.data", this.data), console.log("labels", this.data.data['labels'])

Comment: 0: {_id: "605b262c36c70c354015a945", serial: "12345", sourceApi: "ASDASD", resultApi: "ASDASD", labelApi: "ASDASD", …}
1: {_id: "605b26bd36c70c354015a946", serial: "3333", sourceApi: "sdfdg", resultApi: "sdsf", labelApi: "gggg", …}
2: {_id: "605b26ea2e5ea63080dd4796", serial: "3333", sourceApi: "sdfdg", resultApi: "sdsf", labelApi: "gggg", …}

Comment: So the response is an array of objects. it should work    <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let x of data">
                <td>{{x?.serial}}</td>
                <td>2012/01/01</td>
                <td>Member</td>
                <td>
                  <span class="badge ba+dge-success">Active</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            
            </tbody>

Comment: <table *ngIf="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped ">

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.